# Java8 Optional to replace method that throws several exceptions

Tags: java, function, java-8

Some code we have throws different exceptions during it's execution. I want to replace exceptions with `Optional`; but optional can only inform users that value does not exist. I need more details about various issues that happens during the execution. I need this details mostly for the error messages and getting the right error code.

What is the intended way to use `Optional` in this case?

Comment: Look into `Either` pattern.

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162407/is-there-an-equivalent-of-scalas-either-in-java-8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Optional` is not intended to replace exceptions, especially if there are different kinds of exceptions and the caller is expected to deal with them.

If your method never returns `null` unless there is an exception, then introducing `Optional` to a type that was `@NotNull` before seems like quite a step backwards regarding type/null-safety.

Just keep the exceptions.