# Java template function

Tags: java, generics

I have a function that sometimes has to return a `Date` other times a `DateTime` (Joda-Time).

```java
static public <T extends Object> T convertTimeForServer(DateTime toSave) {
    DateTime temp = null;
    try {
        temp = toSave.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(getServerTimeZone()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    T toReturn = null;
    if (toReturn.getClass().equals(temp)) {
        return (T) temp;//Return DATETIME
    } else {
        return (T) temp.toDate();//Return DATE
    }
}
```

Is it the right approach?
How to use it?

like this (timerHelper is the name of class):

```java
DateTime t = timerHelper.<DateTime>convertTimeForServer(new DateTime());
Date t2 = timerHelper.<Date>convertTimeForServer(new DateTime());
```

or

```
DateTime t = (DateTime)timerHelper.convertTimeForServer(new DateTime());
Date t2 = (Date)timerHelper.convertTimeForServer(new DateTime());
```

And how to use this function instead?

```java
static public <T extends Object> T current_Moment(){
    return convertTimeForServer(new DateTime());
}
```

Comment: Just curious: What happens if you return DateTime always?

Comment: No because in the code sometimes I need a `Date` other times a `DateTime`

Comment: Well, in those times when you need a date, call `t.toDate()`.

Comment: toReturn.getClass() will always throw a NullPointerException

Comment: you can just return DateTime always and manipulate it afterward to fit your needs, whats complicated about that!

Comment: That is true! But can I wrap the complexity using this template or not?

Comment: Well.. actually not. You are making the method complicated. If you always return same type of result, it makes it consistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you're being too clever trying to use generics here. Because you don't have polymorphism on return types doesn't mean you should resort to generics to try and achieve that effect.

You can implement this simply as two methods: `public static Date convertToDateForServer(DateTime toSave) {...}` and `public static DateTime convertToDateTimeForServer(DateTime toSave) {...}`. The calling code seems to know what it wants, so it can simply call the method needed. If there really is a complex commonality to both methods, make a private method that both can call internally.

Answer (score 2):

If Java 8 is available you could always implement an [Either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26162407/823393) using the new [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the tricky areas of Generics. The only way to get this to work would be to take a Class argument, so the method knows what type of object to create. It can't know at the moment, because of [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

Alternatively (much simpler) is to always return `DateTime` and do away with generics here.

The client will always know what it wants, and if the client wants a `Date`, it can create one from the `DateTime` far more easily than what you are trying to do.

Example:

Client 1 wants a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime result = service.convertTimeForServer(dt);
```

Client 2 wants a `Date`:

```
Date result = service.convertTimeForServer(dt).toDate();
```