# Throwing exception from recursive function

Tags: java, exception

I built a library/module for a bigger application which throws an Exception from a function. The Exeption is thrown in case the file is not found or file contains bad format.

The method looks something like:

```
Shape parse(String path) throws Exception {
  // load file, parse file, guild graph

  if ( file does contain bad format ) {
    throw new Exception("bad format");
  }

  parse(newPath); 
}
```

The exception will terminate my module since it will be caught in the application which uses my module, but that's alright since the format was bad.

What I would like to know is this - is it is a bad practice, throwing Exceptions from recursive functions like that?

Comment: Nope, totally normal practice.  I'd say it's better than swallowing (not reporting) the exception or than throwing an unchecked exception.  Makes you module easy for others to understand and use.

Comment: It is very bad practice to throw a general `Exception`, throw a `BadFormatException` instead. (and declare only that one to be thrown or even make it unchecked)

Comment: luk actually makes a good point, I assume you were only using `Exception` here as an example, but not in production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on your programming style.

Throwing exceptions inside a recursive function is not bad, but throwing

```
new Exception("bad format")
```

is not a very good practice, since it would be hard to catch the specific exception. You should instead create your own exception or use

```
java.text.ParseException
```

as a checked exception.

On the other hand, you may also return a Either type to avoid checked exceptions. There are existing answers about implementing it in Java:
[Is there an equivalent of Scala's Either in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162407/is-there-an-equivalent-of-scalas-either-in-java-8)