# Is it possible to return two different kinds of types from an Observable that goes into a map/flatMap?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, rx-java

I am wondering if is possible to do something like this:

I have a function that returns a Observable like this:

```
Observable<JSONObject> = someMethodCall().map( x -> {
/// do something
return new JSONObject().put("id", 12346");
});
```

Now I wanna go deep and in the //do something want to add some logic, so I can return an `Observable.error` , for this I cannot use `map` but either flatMap, I am wondering if there is any way to use flatMap to handle this kind of behaviour?

Comment: I assume that you are using RxJava Observables here?

Comment: yes, RxJava Obserfables

Comment: You want something like [Either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162407/is-there-an-equivalent-of-scalas-either-in-java-8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you'd like errors to be propagated via `onError`, so that you can use things like `onErrorReturn` or `onErrorResumeNext`, you can use `flatMap` like so:

```
Observable<JSONObject> = someMethodCall().flatMap( x -> {
    try {
      //do something....
      return Observable.just(new JSONObject().put("id", 12346"));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      return Observable.error(t);
    }
  });
```