# How can I do this in java without using Either?

Tags: java, functional-programming, refactoring, either

I have a function that returns String.

```java
private String processQuery(String[] args){
    //code logic
}
```

Returned result can either be a answer `(Your account detail is $account_detail.)` or response `(Sorry I cannot understand you?)`. Depending upon the result, code will do separate things.
What I came up with is to user `Either<String, String>`.

```java
private Either<String,String> processQuery(String[] args){
    //code logic
}

private void reply(String[] args){
    //code logic
    var either = processQuery(args);
    return either.fold((l){
       //returned result is answer

    },(r){
       //returned result is response

    });
}
```

If it returns left then it is answer, if it returns right it is response. But since there is not Either type in java so I tried passing AtomicBoolean around.

What is the better solution for this only using **java stl**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26162407/14066835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to make the method take two lambda functions that corresponds to a correct and an incorrect answer and then call only the appropriate one

```
private void processQuery(String[] args, Consumer<String> correct, Consumer<String> incorrect){
    if (args.length == 0) {
        incorrect.accept("Sorry I cannot understand you?");
        return;
    }

    correct.accept("Your account detail is $account_detail.");
}
```

which can be called like this

```
private void reply(String[] args){
    processQuery(args, (
        reply -> System.out.println("Success!, " + reply)
    ),
    (
        reply -> System.out.println("Fail, " + reply)
    )
    );
}
```

or create variables for the different functions

```
Consumer<String> badAnswer = reply -> System.out.println("Fail, " + reply);
Consumer<String> goodAnswer = reply -> System.out.println("Success!, " + reply);
private void reply(String[] args){
    processQuery(args, goodAnswer, badAnswer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pair`:

`Pair<String, String> pair = Pair.with("Blah", "Blee");`

See some example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pairs)

A better approach, if your `responses` actually represent some kind of an error, will be to throw an exception of some kind, and to keep the return value of `String` to represent a "good" flow.

Comment: Isn't this JavaFX only?