# Theory of Java methods being able to return one of two types, could this be possible, should it be possible?

Tags: java

Working on some code, and I have a ***potential*** need for my method to return one of two types.

Idea:

- If the method finds scenario 1. return type One.
- If the method finds scenario 2. return type Two.

So to make this formally a question, could this be possible?
Should it be possible, meaning can anyone think of a reason this should not be a part of the java language?

Also I have gotten around this issue in the past by returning an Object[].

But I think it would be interesting to have methods be able to be more specific in the types it could return, limiting to 2 for the theoretical.

some syntax could be:

```
public String[] || List<String[]> processFileData(Path  path){....}
```

Its just a rough idea, so if there are obvious things then fine, but figured I'd ask all the Java experts if this is a good idea or very bad idea?

Comment: That is usually expressed as an Either. Java doesn't have an Either type in the standard library but its easy enough to roll your own. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162407/is-there-an-equivalent-of-scalas-either-in-java-8

Comment: A statically typed language would need to know the return type at compile time.  So you'd need to return a common interface or ancestor type, or wrap the returned result in something that internally handles the different possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort of answered your question youself. In java, you get a polymorphic return by specifying a common interface or a supertype.  I'm pretty sure **Object[]** is NOT a common supertype of **String[]** and  **List<String[]>**. Best you'll get as a return type is Object.

But for a little more color, how would the calling code know what type it was getting?  It would have to introspect the results.

```
if (List<String[]>)
   do one thing
if (String[])
   do another
```

seems like an awful lot of work for the calling code to do. In your example Perhaps you want to return just String[] there is one result and List<String[]>  when there are more than one. If it was my code, I'd introduce a convention of always returning a List<String[]>. If there's one result, there's one item on the list.

Comment: nope Object[] would hold two types String[] at index 0 and/or List<String[]> at index 1

The idea I have here is that Java Standard Library would have this baked in and the compiler would be able to figure it out that is either one type or another, and it would be the callers job to know which type was passed, I guess.

Comment: Its probably a stupid idea because theres always going to be the need to check the type being returned

Comment: Also, I have thought of that as well, always return List and loop through it.

Comment: As for your question
"But for a little more color, how would the calling code know what type it was getting? It would have to introspect the results.

if (List<String[]>) do one thing if (String[]) do another"


I am working with some quick test code for a more involved batch job that is hard to test with the real work, so the method in question would either create a String[] or a List<String[]>.

I think what you have reminded me of is probably the less complicated solution for a non-problem I have created

Comment: I like a me a loosely typed language for batch jobs and transformations. I like to be thinking in terms of maps and lists that get transformed and not object hierarchies.  If you are working on the jvm consider clojure.