How can I define a vararg with three types in Java?
Since I need a Java method to receive any number of objects of three specific classes I decided to use a vararg ... to implement it. However, I have the restriction that these three classes are:

java.lang.String
java.lang.Class
com.company.MyWidget

In my imaginary syntax my method could look like:
  public void myMethod(<String|Class|MyWidget>... elements)) {
    // do something
  }

I was thinking I could use a superclass or interface, but the first two classes belong to the JVM and I cannot touch them.
How can I do this in Java?

Can the array be mixed or it is always the same kind of objects in it?

Maybe Object... ... elements?.

The parameters can be of any mixed types.

@MarcePuente I think Object will work, but won't perform compile-time checks.

Ah, in that case I've pulled the trigger too soon on my answer. You are looking for an "Either" type. Look in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164155/5471574 or have a look at Vavr: https://docs.vavr.io/#_either . Of course if you are having more than 2 possibilities, it will be a hassle to nest it... In case it's not mission critical code, you can get away with something like https://github.com/pakoito/JavaSealedUnions/tree/master

What all these comments are dancing around is that you can't do exactly what you want.  You can make a wrapper type, you can accept Object..., but you can't literally tell the Java compiler to accept these three types and nothing else.

Don't complicate things here. Just make the method accept Object..., validate the input and throw IllegalArgumentException if needed and write a decent javadoc.

That said, why bother with a library when you can just have a sealed type made of three single-element records?

Variadic varargs aren't supported. What you want with the hypothetical syntax isn't in Java, at all. There is no way to write a method that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments such that the compiler marks that call off as invalid if any of the args aren't typed Class, String, or MyWidget.
Solution 1 – 3 methods
Make 3 methods each with args MyWidget..., Class<?>..., etc. Now you can call this method with all mywidgets, or all classes, etc, but you still can't call this method with a hybridized mix of types.
Solution 2 – runtime checks only
Just make one method with Object... and use instanceof to check theem all before continuing. This has the downside that I can call your method passing, say, a bunch of InputStream objects, and the compiler will let it happen; you won't know that's invalid until you actually run the code.
Solution 3 - builder
Something like this:
static class MyMethodBuilder {
  List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
  List<MyWidget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
  List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

  MyMethodBuilder add(Class<?> f) {
    classes.add(f);
    return this;
  }

  MyMethodBuilder add(MyWidget f) {
    widgets.add(f);
    return this;
  }

  MyMethodBuilder add(String f) {
    strings.add(f);
    return this;
  }

  void go() {
    // body of method here
  }
}

Called as:
myMethod()
  .add(SomeWidget.class)
  .add(someInstanceOfWidget)
  .add("someNameOfWidget")
  .go();

Note that this solution doesn't preserve order (you can't tell the difference between first adding a string and then adding a widget, vs the other way around); if you need order preserved you'll need to do more work, such as storing them all in a single List<Object> and using something like:
for (Object v : elems) {
  if (v instanceof MyWidget mw) process(mw);
  else if (v instanceof Class<?> v) process(v.getConstructor().newInstance());
  else if (v instanceof String) processViaString(...);
  else throw new IllegalStateException("BUG: arrived here with a " + v.getClass());
}

Solution 4 - wrapper
Make a wrapper type that accepts any of the 3, then make a method that accepts varargs amount of that wrapper:
sealed interface MyWrapper {
  static StringWrapper of(String in) {
    return new StringWrapper(in);
  }
  static ClassWrapper of(Class<?> in) {
    return new ClassWrapper(in);
  }
  static WidgetWrapper of(MyWidget in) {
    return new WidgetWrapper(in);
  }
}

final class StringWrapper implements MyWrapper {
  final String value;

  StringWrapper(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

final class WidgetWrapper implements MyWrapper {
  final MyWidget value;

  ClassWrapper(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

// same for ClassWrapper

// and then:

void myMethod(MyWrapper... wrappers)

which can be called as:
myMethod(Wrapper.of("Hi"), Wrapper.of(myWidget), Wrapper.of(Foo.class));

Solution 5 - take a step back
A method that accepts either instances of MyWidget, or a class object, or a string sounds like bad design. Accepting Class<?> is almost always wrong; presumably you are going to invoke .newInstance() on that, which is bad, because now you no longer get compile checks checking that the type provided has a public no-args constructor in the first place.
What you probably want is a varargs set of Supplier<MyWidget>. Then you can call:
MyWidget mw = makeAWidget();
myMethod(
  () -> mw, 
  SomeWidgetType::new,
  loadDynamic("foo.bar.fullyqualifiednameof.SomeCustomWidget"));

Where the idea of creating these with a string is kinda icky, that's, obviously, not compile time checkable. loadDynamic is a method that finds that class, checks that it has a no-args constructor that is public and callable. It fails immediately if those things aren't set up properly; if all is well, it returns a supplier that calls .newInstance() each time you get() on it.
And now your varargs method is simple. It takes any number of Supplier<MyWidget>. This is compile-time checked; SomeWidgetClass::new is a valid expression of type Supplier<MyWidget> if it has a public no-args constructor, and isn't if it isn't.

The builder solution sounds like a great approach; it's scalable and easy to implement. In my desperation yesterday I implemented "option #6", where I wrote a small program to create all 1000 methods (1+3+9+27+81+243+729) to cover all possible combinations for up to 6 parameters. Thank you!

How hacky are you allowed to be? The following works, but is "ugly" and you lose the ability to use class-specific methods.
public void myMethod(String... elements) {
  myMethod((Object[]) elements);
}

public void myMethod(Class<?>... elements) {
  myMethod((Object[]) elements);
}

public void myMethod(MyWidget... elements) {
  myMethod((Object[]) elements);
}

private void myMethod(Object... elements) {
  // do it here
}

On the other hand, are you sure that you are not running into an XY-problem? https://xyproblem.info/
I.e., what are you trying to achieve? Is this the best solution for it, or do you have tunnel vision for this problem, which was not your original problem?

Even though this solution does not account for mixed types, it's simple and can resolve a good chunk of the problem.
